# CSS not loads working with iframe tags

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe

I have question regarding . I am using wordpress and create a new page then under that page i am using the  and pass a url by attribute src. So the  is working fine and url's page is showing in it. Here i have to remove some part of html from  and i try to hide them on firebug, they hide there easily but not working when i apply my css to styelsheet file.

My css is not loads/works on , please suggest me a solution so that i can make my page comfortable.

```css
#iframeBody iframe#contentArea {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
}
#iframeHeader iframe#banner {
    display: none;
}
#iframeBody iframe#menuItem {
    display: none;
}
iframe#menuTab {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="http://freightforce.com/MainFrame.aspx?id=Customers_horz_accordion.aspx" width="100%" height="1000px"></iframe>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You must add code.

Comment: sorry, what kind of code @sara

Comment: html css the iframe the css link inside the html

Comment: this is iframe tag-
<iframe src="http://freightforce.com/MainFrame.aspx?id=Customers_horz_accordion.aspx" width="100%" height="1000px"></iframe>
This is css-
#iframeBody iframe#contentArea {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
}
#iframeHeader iframe#banner {
    display: none;
}
#iframeBody iframe#menuItem {
    display: none;
}
iframe#menuTab {
    display: none;
}

Comment: please anyone can help me to get out from it.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: ok dear i will adding it in my question.

Comment: i want to show this <iframe> and css code working on a new domain.

Comment: i am waiting please reply fast and give me a perfect solution.